# htaccess redirects unexpectedly to folder

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, .htaccess, redirect

I have strange for me problem. I'm developing Zend Framework application and have this file structure:

```
/
/application/
/public/
/public/.htaccess
/public/index.php
/public/js/
/public/style/
/public/profile/
/.htaccess
```

My domain point to `folder /`

When I enter the address `example.com/profile/` it goes to the controller profile and this is good.
When I enter the address `example.com/profile` the server redirects me to:
`example.com/public/profile/`

I would like to have a solution that whenever I request:
`example.com/profile/` or
`example.com/profile`

The same page will be rendered but second version gives me a redirect and I don't know why.

The `/.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

The role of this file is to route all traffic from / to /public but without any redirects.

The `/public/.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks.

---

I fixed this. Here is the solution if somebody have the same problem:
To fix this you have to set the following options and disable DirectorySlash

```
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
DirectorySlash Off
```

Now Apache shouldn't add trailing slashes at the end of uri when you pointing to directory.
This also disable redirect to the uri with trailing slash.

Comment: why don't you try `RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [L]` in your first version of `.htaccess`

Comment: Then I Have error in apache log: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Comment: I added to external htaccess this code: RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L] and now I have Internal Server Error because of to much internal redirects...

Comment: I fixed this strange behaviour. What I did is disable DirectorySlash from dir_module: DirectorySlash Off

Comment: add your answer as one of the answer and mark it as accepted. So that if anyone tries to see your question they could see the "green" color mark;

Answer (score 1):

Optionally match the last `/`. Change your .htaccess file to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Does'n work. I try: http://example.com/profil and it redirects me to http://example.com/public/profil/ When I try http://example.com/profil/ then everything is ok.

Comment: Sorry. I have error in this comment. When I try: example.com/profil it redirects to example.com/public/profil/

Comment: Does anybody have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$|^(.*)$  /public/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```